# Calling Object from a handed over class

Tags: c++, object, inheritance

Can you help me how to call a object in a class after handing over the class of the objects.

So I have a Game.cpp in which Constructor I create all Objects.

**Game.cpp**

```
//CONSTRUCTOR
Game::Game(Sep::Interface &io, std::string config): config_(config)
{

  ... some other things ..
//creating objects
  Sep::Property Obstacle(Sep::Field::FieldType::WATER,"OBSTACLE", 'O', true, false, 10, 20);
  Sep::Property Street(Sep::Field::FieldType::WATER,"STREET", 'S', true, false, 20, 10);

};
```

Here the Game.h where you can see its the Consturctor
**Game.h**

```
  class Game
  {
    public:
      //------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // Game constructor & destructor
      //
      Game(Sep::Interface &io, std::string config);
      ~Game() noexcept;

  };
```

Now I have a class build which has a method excecute and which has as parameter the class Game and some parameter as vector.

My Question how do I call the Methods of the Object from the given Gameclass parameter?

**BUILD.h**

```
  class Game;

  class Build : public Command
  {

    public:
      //------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // Constructor
    Build(){};

   //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Destructor
    ~Build() noexcept ;

     int execute(Game &game, std::vector<std::string> &params);
};
```

I tried with something like this, but I wont work :( :
**Build.cpp**

```
int Build::execute(Sep::Game &game, std::vector<std::string> &params)
  {
    if(params.size() == 4 )
    {
      Street s;
          // OR
      game Streets s;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Talk to your teacher. You seem to be confused about the meaning of the terms object and class. This site is not a good place for learning those broad fundamentals.

Comment: Forward declaration of a class (e.g. `class Game;`) can let you use the class as incomplete type, so you could use it for example when declaring a pointer to that class. You should `#include` the `Game.h` file instead to provide full class declaration.

Comment: the forward declaration is only that I can hand over the game as a parameter. All other Headers are included correctly

Comment: @Raedwald Maybe I confused it in this post a bit. I just dont understand how to call the objects of the game class which I hand over in the excecute method.

Comment: Do you just need `game.param`? What do you mean by "calling objects"?

Comment: The object Street for exaple, which I created in the Game.cpp

Answer (score 0):

OK, It give it a try, but I'm not a 100% sure if this is actually your problem:

Game.h:

```
template <typename T> void USE(const T&) {}

namespace Sep
{
    namespace Field
    {
        enum class FieldType { WATER };
    }

    class Property
    {
    public:
        Property(Field::FieldType, const char*, char, bool, bool, int,int);
        void SomeFunction();
    };
    class Interface;
}

class Command {
    virtual int execute(Game &game, std::vector<std::string> &params) = 0;
};

#include <string>
namespace Sep{

class Game
{
    public:
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Game constructor & destructor
    //
    Game(Sep::Interface &io, std::string config);
    ~Game() noexcept;

    std::string config_;
    Sep::Property Obstacle;
    Sep::Property Street;


};
} // namespace Sep
```

Game.cpp

```
namespace Sep
{

Game::Game(Sep::Interface &io, std::string config)
    : config_(config)
    , Obstacle(Sep::Field::FieldType::WATER,"OBSTACLE", 'O', true, false, 10, 20)
    , Street(Sep::Field::FieldType::WATER,"STREET", 'S', true, false, 20, 10)
{

    USE(io);
}

}
```

Build.h

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <vector>
namespace Sep
{

class Build : public Command
{

    public:
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    Build(){};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Destructor
    ~Build() noexcept ;

    virtual int execute(Game &game, std::vector<std::string> &params) override;
};
}
```

Build.cpp:

```
#include "Build.h"
namespace Sep
{
int Build::execute(Sep::Game &game, std::vector<std::string> &params)
{
    if(params.size() == 4 )
    {
    game.Street.SomeFunction();
    }
}

}
```

Maybe this can help you figuring it out.